# React Grid System equivalent to Bootstrap's Grid system?

Tags: reactjs

I'm looking to start styling my React app. I have previously used Bootstrap's Grid system and am now looking for the React grid system. What do React developers commonly use for their App's Grid system / Layout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are targeting only modern browsers (i.e. those with [flexbox support](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox)) you may want to investigate [react-flexbox-grid](https://roylee0704.github.io/react-flexbox-grid/) which offers a set of React components that implement the usual grid concepts like `Row` and `Column`. I've used in successfully in a couple of projects.

This option avoids the need to pull in a whole UI library and only use the grid portions.

Answer (score 1):

I have just used bootstrap, either styling directly with bootstrap css or via this [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/) library.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by React Grid system as it's always CSS grid system. However in my projects I am using [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io) library and I'm guessing it is something you are looking for. The only caveat is that you have to include bootstrap css file (for example from c.d.n.), other than that its working really fine and has great documentation.

P.S. If you would like to only use Grid system, you would then have to find css with bootstrap Grid only, and then import only Grid components from library - `Grid`, `Row` and `Col`.

Answer (score 1):

I used bootstraps grid system for a long time, but after a while I got tired of adding a bunch of classes and it started to make my HTML unreadable. I would suggest using [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). It's a great replacement and is becoming the standard for responsive designs. It's also [supported by all major browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox) which is nice.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [fluid-react](https://github.com/richardzcode/fluid-react) I built. It doesn't need extra CSS.

```
<Container>
    <Row>
        <Col xs="12" sm="6" md="4" lg="3" xl="2">1</Col>
        <Col xs="12" sm="6" md="4" lg="3" xl="2">2</Col>
        <Col xs="12" sm="6" md="4" lg="3" xl="2">3</Col>
        <Col xs="12" sm="6" md="4" lg="3" xl="2">4</Col>
        <Col xs="12" sm="6" md="4" lg="3" xl="2">5</Col>
        <Col xs="12" sm="6" md="4" lg="3" xl="2">6</Col>
        <Col xs="12" sm="6" md="4" lg="3" xl="2">7</Col>
        <Col xs="12" sm="6" md="4" lg="3" xl="2">8</Col>
        <Col xs="12" sm="6" md="4" lg="3" xl="2">9</Col>
        <Col xs="12" sm="6" md="4" lg="3" xl="2">10</Col>
        <Col xs="12" sm="6" md="4" lg="3" xl="2">11</Col>
        <Col xs="12" sm="6" md="4" lg="3" xl="2">12</Col>
    </Row>
</Container>
```